# Java: exceptions and 'might not have been initialized'

Tags: java

I am very new to Java.  I am writing a program to read a file, compute its SHA1 checksum, and write the result to another file.  On any error I am calling a function `err_exit()` that prints a message to stderr and terminates execution by calling `System.exit()` with a specified exit status.  This is approximately what my `main()` function looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String in_fname = "C:/tmp/test.txt"; // not reading args yet
    String out_fname = "C:/tmp/test.sign";
    byte[] file_data;
    String hexdigest;

    try {
        file_data = readFileAsByteArray(in_fname);
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        file_data = new byte[] {0};  // note this line well, please
        err_exit(2, "error opening input file '" + in_fname + "'");
    }

    try {
        hexdigest = hexdigestSha1(file_data);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        hexdigest = "";  // note this line well, please
        err_exit(3, "could not compute SHA1 message digest!");
    }

    try {
        writeFileFromString(out_fname, hexdigest);
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        err_exit(2, "error writing output file '" + out_fname + "'");
    }

    System.exit(0); // success
}
```

There are two lines that I asked you to note well.  Both of those lines exist simply to keep the compiler from complaining that the variable might not be initialized.

As far as the compiler can tell, the catch block might continue.  Actually `err_exit()` will never return so there is no chance of an invalid value being passed along.

So, my question: what is the usual Java idiom for handling this sort of thing?  The row of `try`/`catch` blocks is sort of ugly; would you recommend I make the various functions call `err_exit()` and not have the code explicit like this?  I think I prefer the explicit checks, and the `main()` function is the right place to do the checking, but I'm interested in feedback.

If I am going to have the `try`/`catch` blocks, is this a good way to silence the compiler warnings?

If I were doing this in Python, I'd likely just not catch the exceptions, and let the program stop with a stack trace.  A stack trace on error won't shock the user of this program, since that user is me.  It occurs to me that if I declared my `main()` function as `throws Exception` that I could then not catch the exceptions and it would behave something like Python.  Is that a horrible idea that would make right-thinking Java people shun me?

P.S. If you have a favorite book/web page/whatever of Java idioms that I should read, please mention it.

EDIT: I apologize for the variable names with underscores.  I have already renamed the ones in my real program, but I am going to leave them as-is here.  It's actually because I have spent a lot of time programming in Python and C; I was either using Python "PEP 8" style or generic C style, take your pick.

Comment: post the lines where you declare those two variables.

Comment: I added the missing stuff to make it a complete function.  It looks better because StackOverflow is doing syntax coloring now... it wasn't before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a strong C background.  I assume the compiler complains about variables such as file_data.  Simply add **file_data = null** above the try-catch block.

Some points on the above:

1. I think it is safe to combine all the statements in a single block.  When an exception is thrown, the program will branch to the correct exception block immediately.  It will also look far less ugly.
2. Usually another method is not called within the catch-block as the task should (usually and if possible) be short and to the point.  Handle the error, continue or exit (possibly be re-throwing the exception).
3. System.exit() is evil.  Rather throw a wrapped RuntimeException if you want the system to exit (i.e. an unrecoverable error condition).  System.exit() may result in non-clean exists. Rather use **throw new RuntimeException(e);**
4. Lastly, and if I may be as blunt, the Java convention is to write method/variable names as errExit, rather than err_exit.

Comment: Hmmm.  Before I post a question, I always search StackOverflow to see if it has been answered.  There are numerous discussions of the error "this variable might not have been initialized" and in several of them the advice was "don't initialize the variable until you need it; you want to let the compiler help you, and if you declare/init the variable the compiler is less able to help you."  Do you disagree with that advice in general, or just in cases like I show here?

Comment: I see you edited your question :-) In terms of warnings, try byte[] file_data = null; The RuntimeException will display the stack trace for you... so I think that is what you want.

Comment: I think initialising to avoid the compiler complaining is fine.  Usually lazy initialisation makes perfect sense, but only in cases where the actual value (i.e. non-null) is known. I've been using the "variable = null;" for local variables for ages... I will be most surprised if someone tells me it is bad style (and I would definitely want an alternative).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern about being blunt, but I agree that the name `err_exit()` is not using the Java idiom.  I will change it in my real program, but I think I'll leave it alone here.  (Yes, I have a strong C background; well spotted.)

Comment: Well, some people get very angry if something as trivial as variable name convention is pointed out. Yes, it is definitely not critical. :-)

Comment: So, the Java idiom for letting fatal errors be fatal would be to catch the exception, then "wrap" the exception as `new RuntimeException(ex)` and throw that?  For this program, that should suffice.  For a "real" program where I don't want my users to see a stack trace, I think I would have to catch exceptions individually so I can print better error messages; I want to know if an `IOException` came from the reading function or the writing function.

Comment: Correct, fatal errors that cannot allow the program to continue are typically thrown as RuntimeExceptions.  Later, when you want a "cleaner" exit, you can always catch such methods in the main() function and convert them into pretty messages, etc. before exiting.  If you want to know where the IOException comes from, the easiest would be to try-catch them individually.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler understands that a throw will never return, it does not understand that  err_exit() will not return. If you were to re-write using the exceptions you are ignoring then your code could be cleaner and compiler happier.
You could also consider using Java naming conventions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String inFname = "C:/tmp/test.txt"; // not reading args yet
  String outFname = "C:/tmp/test.sign";
  try {
    processFile(inFname, outFname);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e; // rethrow and let main() die
  }
}        

public static void processFile(String inFname, String outFname) 
    throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  Byte[] fileData = readFileAsByteArray(inFname);
  String hexDigest = hexdigestSha1(fileData);
  writeFileFromString(outFname, hexDigest);
}
```

In the calling routine you can catch the errors. If you really need to distinguish between the the different places IOException could occur then you could catch in your routine and throw a descriptive error.

The minimal fix to your code is just to initialize your variables to null outside of the try catch blocks that set them. Then the compiler would be happy.

Comment: Remember, total Java newbie here.  Putting together your answer with Jaco Van Niekerk's answer, I guess I specify a message like "Unable to read file some_file_name" by passing it to `new RuntimeException(mesg)`.

Comment: If I could accept two answers, I would also have accepted this one.  I did upvote it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like to "throw null;" after calling a method that simply cannot return.

Answer (score 0):

If I were positive that I'd be exiting immediately after a failed access, with no attempt to *act* on the results of the readFileAsByteArray, etc. calls, I'd probably assign null values at the declaration site.  Something like this...

```
byte[] file_data = new byte[] {0};
```

... the rest of your code follows, without the "bogus" assignments in the catch blocks.